# Equivalence definition of amenability (reference)

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a reference (article or book) of the following equivalence of amenability.
Let $G$ be a countable group.

1. There exists a left invariant mean $m : \ell^{\infty}(G) \to \mathbb{R}$
2. For every finite set $S \subseteq G$ and every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a non empty set finite $A \subseteq G $ such that $ \frac{\left| s A \Delta A \right|}{\left| A \right|} <  \epsilon$ for all $s \in S$
3. There exists a sequence $\Phi_n$ of non empty finite sets such that
   $$ \lim_n \frac{ \left| \Phi_n \cap \Phi_n g \right|}{ \left| \Phi_n \right|} =1 $$
   for all $g \in G$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These are all standard. Which books did you check?

Comment: I know these are all standard, but unfortunately, I don't know any beautiful book about amenable groups. I have only the notes of a past course I took. So I was looking for a reference for all these standard facts.